# How to delete users with a certain role in Meteor

Tags: meteor

I am building a **database seeder** to create a random number of users with different roles. My application has two user roles: *'admin'* and *'employee'*.

I have managed to create a method and put it on the server side to seed the database with a random number of employees and one admin. I am trying to have a button that **deletes all the users in the 'employee' role  but not the 'admin' role**.

I have used `alanning:roles` to define user roles. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

I used this function 
 Meteor.users.remove({ "roles" : [ "patron" ] });